# What do llamas in Minecraft PE eat

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My llama is almost dead, what does it eat to give it more health?

Comment: Have you tried Wheat? That's what the computer version llamas eat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try feeding the llama with wheat or a hay bale the wheat gives 2 health points while the hay bale gives 20

[Reference - digminecraft](https://www.digminecraft.com/mobs/llama.php)

Answer (score 0):

It can only eat wheat or hay bales.